# please help!, how to open .urdf.xacro file in Gazebo?

Tags: xacro

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all.

I have to load a .urdf.xacro file using the latest version of gazebo. The file of my interested is :https://github.com/utexas-bwi/segbot/tree/master/segbot_description.

Using Gazebo 1.7, I have no idea how to open up  a   .urdf.xacro   file.
Do I have to convert it first to sdf or do I open it directly?
How do I do that?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2818/please-help!,-how-to-open-.urdf.xacro-file-in-gazebo?/) by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You'll need to run xacro to convert the file to urdf, which Gazebo can handle. This is easy to do if you have ROS installed:

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py <xacro file here>
```

If you don't have ROS installed, I can't think of an easy way. Let me know and I'll post the converted file. That file will undergo some changes in the upcoming week that you won't get if I do so (I maintain the segbot stack).

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/131/piyushk/) with karma: 138 on 2013-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-05-14**:
thank you for your reply.  I do have ros installed. I still have trouble open up the urdf file under Gazebo 1.7.......

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/131/piyushk/) on 2013-05-14**:
Here you go: http://farnsworth.csres.utexas.edu/share/test.urdf

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-05-16**:
thank you very much!